# What are the different vehicle roadways markings?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport-markings

I was going through the AIM (Aeronautical Information Manual) chapter 2, which talks about airport lights and markings. There are 2 types of lines that designate a vehicle roadway. One is a solid line and the other is a zipper line but I could not understand the difference between the two.

[image]

> **Vehicle Roadway Markings.** The vehicle roadway markings are used when necessary to define a pathway for vehicle operations on or crossing areas that are also intended for aircraft. These markings consist of a white solid line to delineate each edge of the roadway and a dashed line to separate lanes within the edges of the roadway. In lieu of the solid lines, zipper markings may be used to delineate the edges of the vehicle roadway.

Comment: Are you confused about the difference between a "solid line" and a "zipper line", or the difference in use? if it's just a use question, it appears to me that the answer is in the quote you provided _In lieu of the solid lines, zipper markings may be used to delineate the edges of the vehicle roadway._ i.e. the airport authority can choose to use either type of line at their discresion.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm unable to understand the difference in use.

Comment: Based on the snippet you posted, there doesn't seem to be a difference. However, I'm no expert, therefore the comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @FreeMan Alright. Thanks for the help.